# can't add header/Access-Control-Allow-Crendentials - python function app

Tags: python, azure, cors, signalr, azure-functions

I can get my signalr code to connect + work no problem in my local environment by setting host with web url

```
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7070,
    "CORS": "http://localhost:4200",
    "CORSCredentials": true
  }
```

Then I deploy it to the portal and go to CORS and add the web url that my storage blob static website is hosted on inside CORS for the signalr function app. When I login to my app with the web url matching cors value I get this for some reason

[image]

Also according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-serverless-development-config) (bottom part of page) I have to enable `Access-Control-Allow-Crendentials`

[image]

but it seems that a function app running on python doesn't have that option
[image]

How can I enable `Access-Control-Allow-Crendentials` in a python function app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no way to set it on azure portal. Not only 'Access-Control-Allow-Crendentials', but also many other config settings cannot set by using azure portal when you are based on linux web app.

To achieve that you want, you can use below cmd in powershell:(It works when you are based on azure web app. azure function is based on web app sandbox, so below cmd also works on function.)

```
az resource update --name web --resource-group yourresoursegroupname --namespace Microsoft.Web --resource-type config --parent sites/yourfunctionname --set properties.cors.supportCredentials=true
```

This is the offcial doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#enable-cors

> If your app requires credentials such as cookies or authentication
> tokens to be sent, the browser may require the
> ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-CREDENTIALS header on the response. To enable
> this in App Service, set properties.cors.supportCredentials to true in
> your CORS config. This cannot be enabled when allowedOrigins includes
> '*'.

On my side, I can change the config setting. Let me know whether you can change the config.:)